# Brace initialization of template struct

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

I am trying to create a linked list template and it works fine for user defined types, but for fundamental types like int behaviour of gcc and clang differ.

```cpp
template<class T>
struct Node {
  Node* next;
  T val;
};

template<class T, class... Args>
Node<T> create(Args... args) {
  return {nullptr, {args...}};
}

int main() {
  create<int>(0);
}
```

While clang compiles that code without problems, gcc generates the following error message.

> error: could not convert ‘{nullptr, {args#0}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘Node<int>’

While I know how to solve this problem, I am still interested whether clang is too permissive and I can't rely on portability of this code, or it is a gcc bug which should be resolved sometime.

Example: https://godbolt.org/g/9gnvNQ

Comment: Removing the braces `{args...}` solves the problem for GCC _and_ Clang.

Comment: This worked: `return {nullptr, args... };`

Comment: If I remove braces then i wouldn't be able to work with structures with user defined constructors. (https://godbolt.org/g/32ZR6K) I know the general solution, but I am interested in what a correct compiler behaviour should be.

Comment: Suggest you add the [language-lawyer] tag .

Comment: GCC does not allow `struct { int x; } v = { {1} };` though it does allow `int x = {1};`. I think it's a bug of GCC.

Comment: @cpplearner for this code clang emits warning `warning: braces around scalar initializer`, which makes me think that it is not really clean code and clang might be too permissive. I would be grateful for results of Microsoft compiler, unfortunately I don't have one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a GCC bug.

First, braces around scalar initializer (list-initialization for scalar type) are permitted according to [[dcl.init.list]/3.9](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.9):

> Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type E and either T is not a reference type or its referenced type is reference-related to E, the object or reference is initialized from that element (by copy-initialization for copy-list-initialization, or by direct-initialization for direct-list-initialization); if a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert the element to T, the program is ill-formed.
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> int x1 {2};                         // OK
> int x2 {2.0};                       // error: narrowing
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Second, `Node<int>` is an aggregate according to [[dcl.init.aggr]/1](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#1):

> An aggregate is an array or a class with
>
> - no user-provided, explicit, or inherited constructors ([class.ctor]),
> - no private or protected non-static data members ([class.access]),
> - no virtual functions, and
> - no virtual, private, or protected base classes ([class.mi]).

So aggregate initialization is performed and `val` is list-initialized with `{args...}` recursively according to [[dcl.init.aggr]/4.2](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#4.2):

> Otherwise, the element is copy-initialized from the corresponding *initializer-clause* or the *brace-or-equal-initializer* of the corresponding *designated-initializer-clause*. If that initializer is of the form *assignment-expression* or = *assignment-expression* and a narrowing conversion is required to convert the expression, the program is ill-formed. [ Note: **If an initializer is itself an initializer list, the element is list-initialized**, which will result in a recursive application of the rules in this subclause if the element is an aggregate. — end note ]

Then [[dcl.init.list]/3.9](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.9) applies again.

As a conclusion, this initialization is well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want something like this:

```
return {nullptr, T{args...}};
```

This explicitly constructs an object `T` using the arguments provided and works with any user defined type as well, shown in the following

```
template<class T>
struct Node {
    Node* next;
    T val;
};

template<class T, class... Args>
Node<T> create(Args... args) {
    return {nullptr, T{args...}};
}

struct Foo {
    string s;
    int i;
};

int main() {
    auto n = create<Foo>("foo", 42);
    cout << n.val.s << ' ' << n.val.i << endl;
}
```